# baking uvmaps to object

Tags: uv, texture-baking

Im having a few issues learning to bake. I have created a model of an onramp, its a solid mesh, consisting of two materials (/w assigned faces) UVMapped, one being the "road" and the second being the "cement". my goal is to bake several UVs into a single one for the final texture.

here is the UVmapped onramp, the end result should be identical, but with a single baked texture.
[image: UVMapped onramp]
[image: Materials][image: mapped]

I've only selected textures, created a new blank image for the render, and pressed bake
[image: ready to bake]
alas its black, there are several lamps on the scene so it's not a lighting issue.
[image: baked]

I also selected the new blank image, went into edit mode, and unwrapped the mesh (its black against the new blank image), after blicking "bake" I get this monstrosity!
[image: attempt unwrap]

whats happening and/or how do I get the proper end result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it! the trick is that you have to create a New UVMap for the bake to draw to.
click "data", expand "UV maps", click the "+" to create a new UVMap. with the new UV map selected, you can create a new blank Image, unwrap, and bake!
[image]

edit: so although it worked that time, i did the same process again on another section and im getting improper bakes!, whats the deal? [image]

edit x2: it was a mirror modifier! even though it was turned off, after deleting the modifier it baked correctly.